# Ghost existing file in hive to new site from custom template?

Tags: site-template, ghosting

I'm developing a Web Template, extending the Blank template. I had some code in a web feature receiver to place webparts on the web's `default.aspx` but ran into a similar issue to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/deploying-webparts-to-default-aspx-with-a-sitedefinition-feature-dependency): the page `default.aspx`, provisioned as a module defined and referenced in `onet.xml`, wasn't created until after the feature receiver had already fired.

If I create a new module in my package in Visual Studio, containing a copy of the `default.aspx` file from 14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts, add this module to my web feature, and deploy, everything works fine.

This seems a bit of a hack, though. In particular, if Microsoft changes the existing `default.aspx`, my sites won't pick up the changes.

Is there any way I can make my module reference the **existing** `default.aspx` in the hive and still ghost it to my custom sites?

(I initially just tried using the XML from the original `onet.xml` in my module - as it does cause the file to be deployed from its original location in the hive - but the module errors because it doesn't contain the referenced file.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating custom provisioning provider. Good example and explanation I found on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185209/SharePoint-Custom-Provisioning-Provider). 
In your `Provision` method overload you can call apply blank template, afterward all files must be provisioned and you can safely add web parts to a default.aspx.
I think this approach best suited your requirements (if I'm not missed something).

Comment: I have come across this method and considered it; I baulked and moved on when I saw it required a `webtemp*.xml` file, which I thought we were trying to avoid. Looking at that Codeplex project, though, it seems solely to be used to tie the template to the provisioner, so I might have another look

Comment: Yep, using this approach this will be a site definition with separate `webtemp*.xml`

Comment: ... but no onet, which kinda compensates for it. I'm just concerned by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#providers which says "...is not recommended due future plans of SharePoint. Interface is not yet deprecated, but I' would not bet my business on this one, even though it might sound really compelling." But it does look like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The default page in a blank site definition just has some sample content? What exactly do you expect Microsoft to change in future that you would be concerned about? If you are deploying a new web template, you should control the deployment of the default page in your web template.